# In SQL Stuck trying to UPDATE a table column from the results of a COUNT

Tags: sql, select, count

I am building up a table for statistical analysis of production data.  I have extracted all the distinct cases, and constructed a count to find how many times each unique case appears in the table.

My issue comes when trying to UPDATE the table's "Number" column with the results from the COUNT

Here is the code I have so far.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE WeightData

INSERT  INTO WeightData (WeightType,WeightIncrement)
SELECT  DISTINCT OutboardWeightTable,OutboardAmount
FROM    ProductionData
WHERE   [Datetime] between '180821_150000' and '180822_000000' and (OutboardAmount > 0)

--UPDATE WeightData
--SET Number = (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    WeightData a
            inner join ProductionData b
                ON (a.WeightType = b.OutboardWeightTable) and (a.WeightIncrement = b.OutboardAmount)
    WHERE   [Datetime] between '180821_150000' and '180822_000000' and (OutboardAmount > 0)
    GROUP   BY a.WeightType,a.WeightIncrement
--)
```

I have commented out the lines that are not working, but when I try to run the query I get the following message.  I have tried many different ways to do this but I feel this is my closes attempt.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestProcedure, Line 24 Subquery
>   returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

When I run the code after commenting those lines, here is the table and the results screen.

[WeightData Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxnz6.png)

[Results from Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPy5i.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE WeightData
    SET Number = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM ProductionData pd
                  WHERE wd.WeightType = p.OutboardWeightTable and  
                        wd.WeightIncrement = pd.OutboardAmount AND
                        pd.OutboardAmount > 0 AND
                        pd.[Datetime] between '180821_150000' and '180822_000000'
                )
    FROM WeightData wd;
```

Comment: I modified the b and p to pd and it works!! I have spent a shameful amount of time stuck on this thanks a lot!